# what is &#160; and why is it causing a weird character on my html output

Tags: php, xslt, character-encoding, character, character-entities

I have the following code in XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="./state" />&#160;<xsl:value-of select="./zip" /><br />
```

It now produces the following:

[image]

Not quire sure what is going on here and **how to remove the weird character**. I think its a character entity for a space? I really am new to xsl and what to do. any help appreciated

Comment: `&#160;` is the numeric version of `&nbsp;`. since you're getting `Â` instead, you've probably got a charadter set mismatch somewhere. Note that core xml doesn't undestand html entities at all, so `&nbsp;` isn't valid xml.

Comment: @MarcB i dont really have vast experience with character set mismatching. I tried changing the line delimiters to unix in eclipse. How do I get the content onto a new file that isnt corrupt

Comment: @jkushner : Your XSL file probably isn't corrupt; it may be that the tool which is serving your rendered file is not outputting in the correct encoding. Unless there is good reason, one should use "UTF-8" consistently.